# website performance on android

Tags: android, jquery, optimization

I have a website (can't post url) that is a long, image-heavy, scrolling website based off the superscrollorama framework : http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

I have done some optimisation for mobile, and have been testing on iPhone - and it performs well on 4S and very well on 5.

On Android however - it lags terribly.

Does anyone have any general tips/quick tips for optimising performance for android? 
And any idea why it would perform very well on 1 device, and horribly on the other?

Currently, i'm optimising by:

- serving smaller images via css backgrounds
- display:none (or sometimes removing elements) that are outside device width

Comment: Don't use transparency and layering - I found that to really help. Anything which draws elements over other elements really causes performance to take a hit.